# Listing preferences with oracle db

Tags: database, oracle

I have a table that shows the preference of a person to a school, like this

```
Person(name, preference_id)
              /
School(school_id, name)
```

each person can have interest in multiple schools(shown by preference_id), like this:

```
Person(John, 132)
Person(John, 133)
School(132, UVA)
School(133, UMBC)

^John would like to go to either UVA or UMBC.
```

I want to write a query that displays ALL the school.name s for-each person.

```
select person.name, school.name
from Person, School
where person.preference_id = school.school_id
;
```

But what I have above would return in a 1 person- 1 school name ratio. Anyway I can modify this so it's 1 person - multi-schoolname? Thanks

Comment: Use `list_agg` function, study this link: http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/listagg.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT p.name,
       LISTAGG( s.name, ',' ) WITHIN GROUP ( ORDER BY s.name ) AS preferences
FROM   Person p
       INNER JOIN School s
       ON ( p.preference_id = s.school_id )
GROUP BY p.name
```